# Regular Expression - Not Followed By - Chaining?

Tags: javascript, regex

The "not followed by" operator is as follows: ( per quick reference at http://regexpal.com/ )

```
?!exprssion
```

Can I chain these together like this?

```
?!(?!exprssion)
```

Why do I ask you ask?

because I need to split() on

```
|
```

or

```
| not follwed by |*
```

but

```
| followed by |** is O.K.
```

See how that is complicated?

Broken Try

```
.split( /\|\*\*|\|(?!\*)/ );
```

This does not work because it splits on

```
|**
```

and I need my split on

```
|
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split on this:

```
\|(?!\*)|\|\*\*
```

This says: either a pipe followed by something not a star (which we will not use to split on), or a pipe followed by 2 stars (use the whole thing to split). I'm not certain from your wording if that's what you're looking for. If you mean "split on pipe, unless it's followed by a single star, but split on a pipe following by 2 stars" then use this:

```
\|(?!\*[^*])
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/Gt0xNQNO

Comment: I think my second solution is what you need, based on your update - added a link to the code in action